# Which DNS settings are used when setting up your server

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration, nameserver

I have a server and want to run my own name server service. Now I have set it up already and it works not, but I do not know where the exact settings are stored.

On my server I use Plesk. When I edit DNS settings there I think it is stored in named.conf. Named is installed on the server, and BIND.

Now I also have a panel from my registrar. This is separate from my server.

Both places I can add the normal MX,A,CNAME, etc records.

Now where is the best way to place this settings. Currently I have the same records on both places, on the server and at the registrar panel.

I am correct to just add all the records at the registrar panel, and remove everything from within PLESK, and just don't run DNS on my server, because it is already done in the registrar panel.

Or should I add the records in both places.

Comment: Any chance of OS details? Windows? Linux? BSD?

Comment: I am on CentOS 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move DNS you will need to access your registrar's cpanel and give your domain new authoritative namesevers (the DNS on your LAN). You should have a backup DNS someplace too.

On your network you will need to configure your zonefile (you can google for help on writing a proper zonefile) and then make sure to open up the proper ports on your firewall to allow DNS traffic from those on the outside who want to query (TCP/UDP 53).

Are you sure you want to do this? If you just want to run a caching DNS server, you can leave your domain DNS with whatever your are using now (assuming your registrar) and just run one locally for LAN requests.

Comment: No I do not need to move anything. Everything is set up correctly. But now I have everything configured in bot my registrars panel and in the zone-file. But I was thinking of removing the zone-file entries.

Answer (score 1):

named.conf is the BIND configuration file, you will have .hosts and .rev files for your
forward and reverse look up settings respectively in your

If your registrar is also your DNS service provider, then you do not need DNS entries in both places.

Comment: Ok thank you I will check and remove the entries from my server. I hope it does not break.